# Angular datepipe showing incorrect date/year in HTML table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date-pipe

I am very new in angular (I have two weeks expirience).
I am using angular 8. I'm trying to format my date value to dd-MMM-yyyy using angular datepipe. The problem I have is that the datepipe is adding ONE year to the actual date value which makes it incorrect.

I have tried to even specify the datepipe timezone and locale but I still get the wrong date. I have tried this `{{member.expiryDate | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy': '+0200' : 'en-ZA'}}`.

If I try to display the date without formatting, I get the correct value which also includes the time that I don't want.

I have attached the displayed date and the actual date. I just need the output to be like 05-Aug-2019 (example). [image]

Comment: what is +0200 ?

Comment: Sorry it's Time zone in South Africa (GMT+2)

Comment: What you get for {{ strDate | date :'dd-MMM-yyyy' }}

Comment: can you able to reproduce it in https://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: I am getting the full month name and incorrect year still. Like this `15-August-2020`

Comment: @Linda check whether your issue is reproducing here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-format-pipe-esbkg8?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @PandiyanCool I will try it.

Comment: @PandiyanCool thank you. I am still getting the wrong date even though the date is correct on your typescript file in FireFox browser. This is what I get `15-Aug-2019 AM`. I have just tried it in Chrome and the date is correct. Does the angular datepipe depend on the browser?

Comment: Works fine for me, I can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: @NicholasK it seems to be related to the browser. It works fine in Chrome (v 75.0.xx). It changes the year in Firefox (v 68.0.1). It shows blank in Edge

Comment: @PandiyanCool sorry I meant to say I am getting `15-Aug-2020 AM` in Firefox

Comment: @Linda got your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like browser based issue
[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-format-pipe-esbkg8?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
today='15-Aug-2019 12:00:00 AM' 
today | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy a': '+0200' : 'en-ZA' }}
```

For me chrome shows

[image]

I would suggest you to look for alternative solution in this case.

And **Firefox** shows (developer edition 68.0b12 (64-bit))

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. I will just format it in the backend and return the formatted value to the front end. Thank you to everyone guys. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: you need separate month and year by ",", not "-". You can use `todayFormat=this.today.replace(/-/g,',')` and use the variable todayFormat with a pipe